# CSS , why adress the "nav a" and not the "li"?

Tags: html, css, web, stylesheet

I have a tutorial, where the following CSS is used to separate list items from each other.

But why do I adress the `nav a` and not the `li` ? Can someone tell me a proper reason to not define the `padding` in `li`? It has a similar effect.

```css
main-header .header-logo {
  float:left;
}

.main-header nav {
  float: right;
}

.main-header ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.main-header li{
  float:left;
}

.main-header nav a {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-header-container">
    <header class="main-header clearfix">
      <a class="header-logo" href="index.html"><h1>ContactFile</h1></a>
      <nav>
        <ul class="header-main-menu clearfix">
          <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact2.html">contact2</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact3.html">contact3</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact4.html">contact4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the example you've given, there's no difference.  There could potentially be other CSS or script somewhere else that changes things, but for what you've shown it will make no different.

Comment: I agree with Archer... So if you intend to have a nav element not having an anchor (like a disabled nav element), it would be best to pad the `li` instead. ;)

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question, so whoever downvoted and voted to close it should really explain themselves.

Comment: Padding will not *separate* `li`...it just makes them bigger. Separation is managed by **margins**

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @Archer This question is asking for opinions. "What is better", and the answer is it depends on your personal preferences or on the situation. In this particular example, you won't see much difference, but if give the <li> elements a border or a background colour, then you could see differences between putting the padding on the <a> or on the <li>. Also, Quentin's answer.

Comment: @MrLister He didn't ask at all for an opinion. Just because the answer in this case is "It's up to your opinion" doesn't make him ask for opinions. I mean, how would he know, that this is opinion based before asking?

Comment: @MrLister As above, he never once asked "what is better".  It was a clear question to me and I'm guessing the OP thought the same, so it's only fair that people explain to **him** (not me) what they think is wrong with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything will work perfect if you apply styles to li but consider you give a padding to a `li`element instead of `a`. It will create this type of effect where only text will be clickable as a link while all the other space will be unclickable as it will be `li` not `a`
[image]